# How to get JS eval() to operate in the parent scope of a QML element

Tags: qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

If I have some JS code as text and I call it in `eval()`, I can then use the functions defined by this statement only in the scope of where the eval() occurred. As far as I can tell, this means that any new JS definitions created from the eval are invisible to the rest of QML. Consider this QML signal handler:

```
Item {
    id: testitem
    onThesourceChanged: {
        eval(thesource)
        testfunction()
    }
}
```

The `testfunction()` was defined in the text “thesource” and **does indeed work** in the signal handler above, printing out some test text; but it is not in the scope of the QML element and therefore cannot be called ever again, as far as I can see. I’ve tried various ideas like putting the `eval()` in a function, or inside `Component.onCompleted`, etc, but I can’t seem to figure out how to get anything created by the `eval()` to be recognized as part of the parent QML element.

For example I want to be able to call `testitem.testfunction()` — but it is not defined outside the scope of this handler.

Comment: where do you get the eval text from?

Comment: @MadeOfAir I'm generating it outside of Qt and before this eval runs, it is in a JS file. In any case, that's not the issue since the text is parsing fine and getting evaluated. I just want it evaluated in the scope of the QML element somehow. But I can't use QML's `import` because that only loads the JS once, and I want to reload the JS file while the app is running, hence need for `eval`

Comment: then why not assign it to a text property on the `testitem`, and re-evaluate whenever necessary?

Comment: @MadeOfAir yes, but how to re-evaluate it? The `eval` needs to be somewhere, and if it's in a function, then the evaluation is limited to the scope of that function.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the variable in the scope where you want to access it later. Use `eval()` to initialize it in a child-scope:

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            testitem.thesource = "myfunction = function(text) { return text.toLowerCase() }"
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: testitem
        property var myfunction: function(text) { return text.toUpperCase() }
        property var thesource;
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: myfunction("Kullo – Secure Messaging")

        onThesourceChanged: {
            eval(thesource);
            text = myfunction("Kullo – Secure Messaging")
        }
    }
}
```